# Extract data from file, process and then next line

Tags: python, file, nested

I need to read a lines from two files. Extract data from the first line of file A and compare it with each line in file B. When I'm done with file B, I have to read next line in file A and compare it with all lines in file B, and so on ans so forth. I tried to use file.readline(), but when I use a while, it only prints the last line

```
import sys
def ReadFile():
  name1='RoutingTable.txt'
  try:
    arch_table= open(name1,'r')
  except IOError:
      print 'Cannot Open', name1   
      sys.exit()

  while True:
   route=arch_table.readline()
   print route
      if not route:
            break
      pass
```

Answer (score 1):

Something to get you started:

```
$ cat f1
kalle
trazan
apanzon

$ cat f2
dipsy
poo
laalaa
trazan


$ cat two.py
#!/usr/bin/env python

with open('f1') as fd1:
    for line in fd1:
        with open('f2') as fd2:
            for other_line in fd2:
                if line == other_line:
                    print line
```

Output:

```
$ ./two.py 
trazan
```

Comment: thank you. Can you explain what with does, sorry I'm practically new i n this.

Comment: If you new to python I'd recommend the official tutorial on docs.python.org. The `with` construct automatically closes the filehandle when it goes out of scope. For each line in file1 the code loops through all lines in file2 to see if there is a match with the line from file1. Hope it helps.

Comment: Best way to say thanks is to upvote and accept :-) Glad I could help and welcomed to SO!